# Can a JS function accept an argument object without any defined parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

i.e. is there any way to accommodate an argument, e.g. the string, if a function is invoked like so: `foo('str')` while written like so:

```
function foo(){
  console.log(<the_argument>)
}
console.log(foo('str')) // <--- 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object to do the same:

```
    function foo() {
      if(arguments.length >0) {
         return arguments[0];
      }
    }
    console.log(foo('str'));
```

Additional info:
ES6 brings in [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) & [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) syntax which help when working with functions

Answer (score 3):

You can use "arguments" keyword to get the arguments provided in foo('str'). For ex.

```
function foo(){
  var arg = arguments; // contains array of arguments provided
  console.log(arg[0]);
}
console.log(foo('str')); // prints "str"
```

Comment: thank you for the useful answer and demonstration with your code!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Arguments passed to a JS function can be retrieved by using the `arguments` array inside the function.

```
function func1(a, b, c) {
   console.log(arguments[0]);
   // expected output: 1

   console.log(arguments[1]);
   // expected output: 2

   console.log(arguments[2]);
   // expected output: 3
}

func1(1, 2, 3);
```

For more information please refer to the Mozilla documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: Thanks for the link and the demonstration!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. There is an implicit `arguments` local variable. It is iterable and can be used like an array (although it isn't an array) to access all the function's arguments without relying on any formal parameters.

```js
function foo()
{
   for (i in arguments) 
   { 
  console.log(arguments[i]); 
   }
}
foo('str','wasdf',9)
```

See [Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), for a more detailed definition.

Comment: I'm not sure that I completely understand your question, but arrays are distinct types from general Objects. Still, arguments are not true arrays (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: So *thats* why you didn't select my answer as *the* answer?! :-)

Comment: lol - no, it was cuz you didn't vote for my question ;) I chose the one just cuz it had links and some add'l info. But I did vote yours up :)

Answer (score 0):

<del>Obviously not. You can check your self.</del> If you are in angular side then you have something call DI and you can have service injected.

But you can do like make variable outside and access inside a function. If you see fit, you can test it.

Actually, you can do it, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: thanks for the answer, but per the other answers, I've verified that I can use the `arguments` object, e.g. arguments[i].